# Buttons that make different actions

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

As you can see, I have this wrapanel and its event is called "KinectTitleButtonClick"; the event applies to all buttons. I want a different method for each button so that each button would do a different action.

```
<WrapPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="wrapPanel" Orientation="Vertical" k:KinectTileButton.Click="KinectTileButtonClick">
            <!-- items for design layout.  They will be replaced at runtime. -->
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="1" Click="KinectTileButton_Click" />
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="2"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="3"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="4"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="5" Click="KinectTileButton_Click_1" />
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="6"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="7"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="8"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="9"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="10"/>
            <Image Height="150" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Width="200" />
        </WrapPanel>
```

In C# I have this method for KinectTitleButtonClick.

```
 private void KinectTileButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var button = (KinectTileButton)e.Source;
        var wineModel = button.Tag as WineModel;
        var selectionDisplay = new SelectionDisplay(wineModel);
        this.kinectRegionGrid.Children.Add(selectionDisplay);
        e.Handled = true;

    }
```

I've tried making a "KinectTitleButton_Click_1" method for the button no. 5 with this code, but it doesn't work. It still triggers the same event

```
private void KinectTileButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Message");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
private void KinectTileButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    var button = (KinectTileButton)e.Source;
    var wineModel = button.Tag as WineModel;
    var selectionDisplay = new SelectionDisplay(wineModel);
    this.kinectRegionGrid.Children.Add(selectionDisplay);

    switch(button.Label.ToString())
    {
        case "5":
            KinectTileButton_Click_1(sender, e);
            break;
    }


    e.Handled = true;

}
```

Comment: I haven't tried it until just now and this is the error I get when I try it  "A switch expression or case label must be a b'ool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type"

Comment: Not having the specific example in front of me I'm not sure, but I think you should be able to either cast the label to a string or use .ToString() for the switch to work.

Comment: I've input ToString() and I no longer get the error, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Try putting in a breakpoint to figure out the value of button.Label when you click the fifth button.

Comment: Can you have commands? try this link:http://www.gonetdotnet.info/common-doubts/wpf/send-parameters-with-button-click

Comment: i don`t know how make this..:(

Comment: I don't know where "Koala2" came from unless you changed the "5" to "Koala2". If you did, you'll want to also change it to "Koala2" instead of case "5".

There are cleaner ways, but this is just a simple working example on how to use a switch to handle events from multiple buttons.